# How to remove url query string in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have this url:
`http://www.example.com/?option=com_php&Itemid=1&ep=3&lang=us`

I want to this url:
`http://www.example.com/?ep=3&lang=us`

How to remove this line option=com_php&Itemid=1& in htaccess?

I have read many responses on this subject and I searched the web, but unfortunately no solution works. Please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=([^&]+)&Itemid=([^&]+)&(ep=[^&]+)&(lang=[^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?%3&%4 [L,R]
```